# Running a Shell Script from Raspberry Pi Webpage

Tags: php, shell, networking, raspberry-pi

I am running an Apache webpage on my Raspberry Pi. When I connect to the Pi's network I am able to access that webpage. On this webpage I would like to have a button that runs a shell script located inside the pi itself. All the script is doing is running fswebcam so that the usb webcam attached to the pi takes a screenshot. What I am not able to do is call that .sh script from the pi's webpage. Perhaps running it as .cgi from the cgi-bin? Not even sure how the syntax would look in php. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the .sh script running fswebcam in case its relevant:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
fswebcam -r 1920x1080 --no-banner /var/www/html/$DATE.jpg
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can either run it via PHP using `system()` or `exec()` or `shell_exec()` or similar. Alternatively configure apache to run shell scripts using cgi-bin (maybe http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html can help)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$last_line = system('path/to/your_script.sh', $retval);
echo "<pre>".print_r($last_line,true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r($retval,true)."</pre>";
```

If you open the page this should run the script and print as much informationa bout that as possible in a readable way.

Comment: Absolute path dosnt seem to go through, I get a value of 0 displayed when I open the page. I changed it to refer to its own local folder and moved the .sh there and now it returns 127. Not sure what to conclude from these numbers though?

Comment: Did you get a snapshot from the webcam? Otherwise take a look into the webcam itself. If you can access it from the commandline there should also be information about the results you can get there.

Comment: When I run the shell from the command line I get a snapshot, but when I open the webpage nothing happens.

Comment: I am attempting to run it as a .cgi from /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ by typing its location into the browser bar and I get this error:

"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

But if I run a simpler script from the same folder it works, like a hello world script: 

#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n\n"

echo "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

Comment: Then check the error log for what you get in there.

Comment: I guess the webpage user dosnt have enough permissions to access /dev/video0/ to execute the webcam function, here's the output:

Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
Error opening device: /dev/video0
Permission denied
Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0
End of script output before headers: webcam.cgi
caught SIGTERM, shutting down

It seems that the .cgi file is being read, so apache is doing its job. But I changed the permissions on /dev/ and /dev/video0 and still the same error, suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I can help you with that. I know how to setup stuff in PHP, but I don't know that much about permissions and how to solve problems with it. But you should edit the result of these comments into your question so other can help you with it.